# How does the Drupal LDAP module manage passwords?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I'm currently configuring the LDAP module for my Drupal site (7.37) and I wanted to know if it's my AD password that is stored in my database (table users).

If it's not my AD password, is it just a random string? What it is and how does it works?

Thank you.

PS: I haven't configured anything to store the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all explained in the documentation and help text provided in the admin screens of the module.

Drupal supports multiple login sources. When a user logs in an entry for the type of login used for the person is stored in `user_auth` as an example.

By default LDAP does not store for example the AD password of the user within Drupal. It stores a dummy password and passes login info to LDAP from the login form upon a login attempt.

If you configure LDAP to `sync` drupal account information to and from Drupal then Drupal may store the password your LDAP accounts -- but this depends on how you've configured your LDAP service, and how you want the drupal ldap module to interact with it.